Including Variables like Age, Ethnicity etc in Design Matrix with Paired Samples (EdgeR)
I'm analysing differential RNA expression in patients before and after treatment using EdgeR. Primarily, I'm interested in which proteins are differentially affected by the treatment. Secondarily, I want to see if treatment outcomes (differential RNA expression) are affected by patient characteristics such as age, sex etc
This all works fine when including just patient ID and timepoint. However, I'd like to know how factoring patient characteristics such as age, ethnicity and sex into the model affects the result of the differential expression analysis.
When I try to do this, the code throws an error (just including age for simplicity)
Patient <- factor(meta.data_sub$Study_ID) Time <- factor(meta.data_sub$Group3, levels=c("0","1")) Age <- factor(meta.data_sub$Age) design <- model.matrix(~0 +Patient +Age +Time)
dge <- estimateDisp(dge, design = design) fit <- glmQLFit(dge, design = design,dispersion=dge$common.dispersion) qlf <- glmQLFTest(fit)
`Error in glmFit.default(sely, design, offset = seloffset, dispersion = 0.05, : Design matrix not of full rank.  The following coefficients not estimable:
 Age23.7 Age28.3 Age30.5 Age31.3 Age31.5 Age31.8 Age31.9 Age32.8 Age33.5 Age35.9 Age36.2 Age36.4 Age37 Age37.5 Age38.7 Age39.4 Age40.1 Age40.5 Age41.8 Age42.4 Age44.4 Age46 Age47 Age47.5 Age48.5 Age48.6 Age48.7 Age48.9 Age50 Age50.1 Age50.5 Age51.2 Age51.7 Age51.9 Age53.2 Age54.1 Age54.5 Age56.8 Age58.1 Age60.6 Age64.3 Age67.3`

I also tried with Age as a numeric but get a different error
`Error in glmFit.default(sely, design, offset = seloffset, dispersion = 0.05, : Design matrix not of full rank.  The following coefficients not estimable:
 Age`

From reading other questions, might it be that because patient characteristics across timepoints are the same I'm generating a linear dependency? In which case, can I leave out Patient from the design?

You're doing a paired analysis, so every possible per-patient attribute is already included in the design. If you combine the patient ID with other per-patient variables then this is inevitably confounded, which is what the error tells you. Hence, by including patient ID you cannot include any other patient characteristic.
Sure, you could remove the patient ID from the design, but then the analysis is no longer as powerful as it is right now, and you probably need quite a sample size to bring analysis to significance.

This is along the line I was thinking. My sample size is about 50 pairs. Is there a way to statistically characterise which model fits better, using a paired design or an additive design with all available patient characteristics?

Pairing has two advantages in my head. First, it included absolutely all patient characteristics, even those that you don't know, and it is a single covariate rather than many, so you have more degrees of freedom available for your analysis, hence it's most powerful.

It sounds like what you actually want is a mixed model, which edgeR (or DESeq2) doesn't support out of the box.

What would be the advantage of a mixed model here over a simple analysis that blocks for patient?

By including a random intercept (rather than a fixed parameter) per subject you can address the correlation between within-subject observations & still get inference on other parameters, because they should no longer be collinear with the previously fixed subject effect. You might also recover more degrees of freedom (although these will likely have to be approximated..) because you no longer need one parameter per subject.
